# Separate foreach items and print them individually

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm currently having some trouble trying to decouple this foreach array. It basically prints all checkboxes as a group (widget) in a form.

```
<?php foreach ($widgets as $id => $widget): ?>  
 <label for="<?php print $widget->id; ?>">
      <?php print $widget->label; ?>
 </label>
      <?php print $widget->id; ?>
```

Doing print_r function on $widgets shows the ff: array:

```
Array
(
[filter-tid] => stdClass Object
    (
        [widget] => 
Option 1
Option 2
Option 3
        [operator] => 
        [label] => label here
        [id] => edit-id-here
    )

[filter-tid_1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [widget] => 
Option 1
Option 2
Option 3
        [operator] => 
        [label] => label here
        [id] => edit-id-here
    )

   ....... and so on....
```

How would I go about printing each item in the foreach separately? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just nest the `foreach` and loop over `$widget->widget`

```
<?php foreach ($widgets as $id => $widget): ?>
    <?php foreach ($widget->widget as $option): ?>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but can you please expand this to a more newbie-friendly way?

Comment: @PatrickDanTan what don't you understand exactly?  `foreach` is just used to iterate over arrays; Isn't `$widget->widget` also an array?